# Graduate real analysis integration question.

Tags: analysis

Let $f,g\in C^{0}\left(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$. Assume that $\intop_{0}^{\infty}f\left(t\right)dt=\infty$ and $\intop_{0}^{\infty}g\left(t\right)dt=\infty$.

Prove that $\intop_{0}^{\infty}\min{\left(f\left(t\right),g\left(t\right)\right)}dt=\infty$.

Comment: Is this true?  Pick some $h(x)  \in C^0(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R}_+)$ with $\int h < \infty$.  Let $f$ be $h$ with a "bump" added to every interval $[k,k+1]$, for k odd, and $g$ be $h$ with a bump added to every interval $[n,n+1]$, for $n$ even.  Then $\min(f,g)=h$, but if the bumps are chosen correctly, $\int f= \int g = \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take $f(x):=\max\{0,\sin(x)\}$ and $g(x):=\max\{0,\sin(x+\pi)\}$. Then $\int_0^\infty f=\infty=\int_0^\infty g$, but $\min\{f(x),g(x)\}=0$ for each $x$ and hence $\int_0^\infty\min\{f,g\}=0$.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, g(x) = \begin{cases} x, &x\leq 1 \\ \frac{1}{x}, &x>1\end{cases}$.

Obviously, $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \infty$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x) dx = \infty$, but: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}min(f(x),g(x)) dx = \int_{0}^{1}x dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} dx = \frac{3}{2}$$

So I guess the statement is false.